# Laravel 5.4 Cashier add subscription

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

I've followed Laravel docs exactly for creating a new subscription via Cashier. My controller looks like this:

```
public function saveSubscription(Request $request)
{
    $plan = Plan::find($request->input('plan'));
    //$user_id = Auth::id();
    //$user = User::find($user_id); // work but ugly
    //$user = $request->user(); // same error
    $user = Auth::user();

    $user->newSubscription($plan->name, $plan->name)->create($request->input('stripeToken'), [
        'email' => $request->input('stripeEmail'),
    ]);
```

All of these attempts to get the `User` model from the `Auth` or `Request` fail with the following error:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::newSubscription()`

The only thing that works is getting the user ID via the `Auth::id()` call and then looking it up manually.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you add the Billable trait to your user model? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing

Comment: @CUGreen-- thanks, that's it! I thought I had added that when I published the Cashier elements. Please add as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `Billable` trait to your User model

```
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Billable;
}
```